# Where is spec_helper.rb file located?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I was trying to run the tests using `rspec spec.rb`

But it is giving me following warning:

```
Deprecation Warnings:

Requiring `rspec/autorun` when running RSpec via the `rspec` command is deprecated.
```

I found the [issue](https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/issues/68) and to suppress this I need to delete `require 'rspec/autorun'` from `spec_helper.rb`

As I am not using Rails, there is no such file, how should I fix this?

Comment: What does your test structure look like? Do you only have **one** test file, called `spec.rb`? (What's in the file?) Or, do you have a whole folder of tests, organised like `spec/path/to/files/something_spec.rb`?

Comment: It *looks like* you only have one `spec.rb` file which contains the line: `require 'rspec/autorun'`. In which case, all you need to do is delete that line!

Comment: You are correct, deleting that line works. Thanks!

Comment: if you run `rspec --init` it will generate a spec/ folder including spec_helper.rb